# Bucle for con representación gráfica de histogramas con r base

Tags: r

Quiero representar cuatro histogramas de frecuencias en una misma figura, por medio de de for.

1. Defino las 4 variables a representar.

   ```
    Normal1 <- rnorm(n = 100,mean = 10,sd = 5)
    Normal2 <- rnorm(n = 100,mean = 10,sd = 5)
    Normal3 <- rnorm(n = 100,mean = 10,sd = 5)
    Normal4 <- rnorm(n = 100,mean = 10,sd = 5)
   ```
2. Para hacerlo automáticamente, declaro los cuatro nombres, que serán las entradas para hacer el plot del histograma con r base.

   ```
    Normal = c('Normal1',
               'Normal2',
               'Normal3',
               'Normal4')
   ```
3. Creo el script:

   ```
    par(mfrow=c(2,2))

    for(i in 1:length(Normal))
    {
       hist(Normal[i])
    }
    par(mfrow=c(1,1))
   ```
4. Al correrlo da el siguiente error: **"Error in hist.default(Normal[i]) : 'x' must be numeric"**
5. Trato de solucionarlo haciendo:

   ```
    as.data.frame.noquote(Normal,optional = T)
    as.data.frame.noquote(Normal[1],optional = T)
   ```

Sigue sucediendo el mismo error.

6. El problema es que trata de leer un objeto con comillas: 'Normal[i]' y por eso ocurre el error.

¿Alguna forma de resolver este problema?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que estas esperando que esto: `Normal[i]` sea el vector `Normal1` y lo cierto que no les. En tu código `Normal` es un vector de caracteres por lo que `Normal[1] = "Normal1"` así como `Normal[2] = "Normal2"`. Luego simplemente terminas haciendo `hist("Normal1")` que obviamente dará error por no ser un vector numérico.

Lo que entiendo que estas buscando es una lista con cada normal, donde aquí sí, cada elemento represente uno de los vectores:

```
normales <- list(
  rnorm(n = 100,mean = 10,sd = 5),
  rnorm(n = 100,mean = 10,sd = 3),
  rnorm(n = 100,mean = 10,sd = 10),
  rnorm(n = 100,mean = 3,sd = 10)
)
```

Generamos un lista con 4 vectores que siguen distintos parámetros de una distribución normal. Luego para generar el histograma de cada uno:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
for(n in normales) {
  hist(n)
}
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

`for(n in normales)` nos retorna en cada iteración cada una de las muestras. Las listas se pueden acceder también por índice, pero hay que tener en cuenta que la versión equivalente es con doble corchete `n <- normales[[1]]`. El corchete simple en este caso, nos entrega un lista de un elemento, el corchete doble directamente el elemento.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, en efecto creando una lista lo puede resolver. Como comentario adicional, aplica también para los casos en que los objetos de la lista tienen nombre (ya que solo importa el índice). Los datos provenían de objetos generados por otros cálculos y la lista resultó la opción adecuada para resolver el problema.